Can't detect ADS-B messages via SDR
I'm making a program that detects ADS-B messages with SDR HackRF One.
The problem is program works only with test file (I found it at dump1090 repo) and if you launch detection via SDR program won't detect anything and I don't know why.
Here is the test file I found
Here's main logic:
#include "adsbworker.h"
#include <SoapySDR/Formats.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFile>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

static uint16_t maglut[129 * 129];
static int maglut_initialized = 0;

struct IcaoCacheEntry {
    uint32_t addr;
    time_t timestamp;
};

static IcaoCacheEntry icaoCache[MODE_S_ICAO_CACHE_LEN];

const char *ADSBWorker::ais_charset = "?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ????? ???????????????0123456789??????";

const uint32_t ADSBWorker::mode_s_checksum_table[112] = {
    0x3935ea, 0x1c9af5, 0xf1b77e, 0x78dbbf, 0xc397db, 0x9e31e9, 0xb0e2f0, 0x587178,
    0x2c38bc, 0x161c5e, 0x0b0e2f, 0xfa7d13, 0x82c48d, 0xbe9842, 0x5f4c21, 0xd05c14,
    0x682e0a, 0x341705, 0xe5f186, 0x72f8c3, 0xc68665, 0x9cb936, 0x4e5c9b, 0xd8d449,
    0x939020, 0x49c810, 0x24e408, 0x127204, 0x093902, 0x049c81, 0xfdb444, 0x7eda22,
    0x3f6d11, 0xe04c8c, 0x702646, 0x381323, 0xe3f395, 0x8e03ce, 0x4701e7, 0xdc7af7,
    0x91c77f, 0xb719bb, 0xa476d9, 0xadc168, 0x56e0b4, 0x2b705a, 0x15b82d, 0xf52612,
    0x7a9309, 0xc2b380, 0x6159c0, 0x30ace0, 0x185670, 0x0c2b38, 0x06159c, 0x030ace,
    0x018567, 0xff38b7, 0x80665f, 0xbfc92b, 0xa01e91, 0xaff54c, 0x57faa6, 0x2bfd53,
    0xea04ad, 0x8af852, 0x457c29, 0xdd4410, 0x6ea208, 0x375104, 0x1ba882, 0x0dd441,
    0xf91024, 0x7c8812, 0x3e4409, 0xe0d800, 0x706c00, 0x383600, 0x1c1b00, 0x0e0d80,
    0x0706c0, 0x038360, 0x01c1b0, 0x00e0d8, 0x00706c, 0x003836, 0x001c1b, 0xfff409,
    0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000,
    0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000,
    0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000
};

ADSBWorker::ADSBWorker(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent),
    device(nullptr),
    stream(nullptr),
    running(false)
{
    samplesPerBit = 2;
    samplesPerFrame = samplesPerBit * 120;

    if (!maglut_initialized) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 128; i++) {
            for (int q = 0; q <= 128; q++) {
                maglut[i * 129 + q] = round(sqrt(i * i + q * q) * 255);
            }
        }
        maglut_initialized = 1;
    }

    memset(icaoCache, 0, sizeof(icaoCache));
}

ADSBWorker::~ADSBWorker()
{
    stopSDR();
}

void ADSBWorker::startSDR()
{
    float frequency = 1090e6;
    float sampleRate = 2e6;
    float bandwidth = 2e6;

    SoapySDR::Kwargs args;
    args["driver"] = "hackrf";
    device = SoapySDR::Device::make(args);

    if (!device) {
        QString errorMsg = "Failed to initialize HackRF";
        qCritical() << errorMsg;
        emit errorOccurred(errorMsg);
        return;
    }

    device->setSampleRate(SOAPY_SDR_RX, 0, sampleRate);
    device->setFrequency(SOAPY_SDR_RX, 0, frequency);
    device->setBandwidth(SOAPY_SDR_RX, 0, bandwidth);

    device->setGain(SOAPY_SDR_RX, 0, "LNA", 40);
    device->setGain(SOAPY_SDR_RX, 0, "VGA", 40);

    stream = device->setupStream(SOAPY_SDR_RX, SOAPY_SDR_CS8);
    device->activateStream(stream);

    running = true;

    readerThread = QThread::create([this]() { readSDRData(); });
    readerThread->start();

    processorThread = QThread::create([this]() { processSDRData(); });
    processorThread->start();
}

void ADSBWorker::stopSDR()
{
    if (!running) return;
    running = false;

    if (readerThread) {
        readerThread->quit();
        readerThread->wait();
        delete readerThread;
        readerThread = nullptr;
    }
    if (processorThread) {
        processorThread->quit();
        processorThread->wait();
        delete processorThread;
        processorThread = nullptr;
    }

    if (device) {
        if (stream) {
            device->deactivateStream(stream);
            device->closeStream(stream);
            stream = nullptr;
        }
        SoapySDR::Device::unmake(device);
        device = nullptr;
    }
}

void ADSBWorker::readSDRData()
{
    if (!device || !stream) return;

    int flags = 0;
    long long timeNs = 0;
    long timeoutUs = 100000;
    const size_t bufferSize = 262144;
    std::vector<std::complex<float>> iqData(bufferSize);

    qDebug() << "Starting SDR data acquisition...";

    while (running) {
        void* buffs[] = { iqData.data() };
        int status = device->readStream(stream, buffs, bufferSize, flags, timeNs, timeoutUs);

        if (status > 0) {
            std::vector<unsigned char> rawIQData(status * 2);

            for (int i = 0; i < status; i++) {
                float real = iqData[i].real();
                float imag = iqData[i].imag();

                unsigned char i_byte = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::round(real * 127.0f + 127.0f));
                unsigned char q_byte = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::round(imag * 127.0f + 127.0f));

                rawIQData[2 * i] = i_byte;
                rawIQData[2 * i + 1] = q_byte;
            }

            {
                QMutexLocker locker(&dataMutex);
                dataQueue.enqueue(rawIQData);
                dataCondition.wakeOne();
            }
        } else if (status == SOAPY_SDR_OVERFLOW) {
            qWarning() << "Buffer overflow!";
            continue;
        } else {
            qWarning() << "readStream error code:" << status;
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "Exiting SDR data acquisition.";
}

void ADSBWorker::processSDRData()
{
    qDebug() << "Starting SDR data processing...";

    while (running) {
        std::vector<unsigned char> dataChunk;

        {
            QMutexLocker locker(&dataMutex);
            while (dataQueue.isEmpty() && running) {
                dataCondition.wait(&dataMutex);
            }
            if (!running) break;
            if (!dataQueue.isEmpty()) {
                dataChunk = dataQueue.dequeue();
            }
        }

        if (!dataChunk.empty()) {
            std::streamsize bytesRead = dataChunk.size();

            if (bytesRead % 2 != 0) {
                bytesRead--;
            }

            if (bytesRead <= 0) {
                continue;
            }

            std::vector<uint16_t> magBuffer(bytesRead / 2);
            computeMagnitudes(dataChunk.data(), magBuffer.data(), bytesRead);

            std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> detectedMessages;
            detectMessage(magBuffer.data(), magBuffer.size(), detectedMessages);

            for (const auto& msg : detectedMessages) {
                mode_s_msg decodedMsg;
                mode_s_decode(&decodedMsg, const_cast<unsigned char*>(msg.data()));

                if (decodedMsg.crcok) {
                    printMessageMM(&decodedMsg);
                } else {
                    qDebug() << "Message with CRC error.";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "Exiting SDR data processing.";
}

void ADSBWorker::processDataFromFile(const QString& filePath)
{
    std::ifstream file(filePath.toStdString(), std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        qCritical() << "Failed to open file:" << filePath;
        return;
    }

    const std::streamsize blockSize = 4096;
    std::vector<unsigned char> rawData(blockSize);

    qDebug() << "Starting file processing:" << filePath;

    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(rawData.data()), blockSize) || file.gcount() > 0) {
        std::streamsize bytesRead = file.gcount();

        if (bytesRead % 2 != 0) {
            bytesRead--;
        }

        if (bytesRead <= 0) {
            continue;
        }

        std::vector<uint16_t> magBuffer(bytesRead / 2);
        computeMagnitudes(rawData.data(), magBuffer.data(), bytesRead);

        std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> detectedMessages;
        detectMessage(magBuffer.data(), magBuffer.size(), detectedMessages);

        for (const auto& msg : detectedMessages) {
            mode_s_msg decodedMsg;
            mode_s_decode(&decodedMsg, const_cast<unsigned char*>(msg.data()));

            if (decodedMsg.crcok) {
                qDebug() << "Message successfully decoded from file.";
                printMessageMM(&decodedMsg);
            } else {
                qDebug() << "Message with CRC error.";
            }
        }
    }

    file.close();
    qDebug() << "File processing completed:" << filePath;
}

void ADSBWorker::computeMagnitudes(unsigned char *data, uint16_t *mag, uint32_t size)
{
    uint32_t j;

    for (j = 0; j < size; j += 2) {
        int i = data[j] - 127;
        int q = data[j + 1] - 127;

        if (i < 0) i = -i;
        if (q < 0) q = -q;

        if (i > 128) i = 128;
        if (q > 128) q = 128;

        mag[j / 2] = maglut[i * 129 + q];
    }
}

int ADSBWorker::detect_out_of_phase(uint16_t *mag) {
    if (mag[3] > mag[2] / 3 && mag[10] > mag[9] / 3) return 1;
    if (mag[6] > mag[7] / 3 && mag[-1] > mag[1] / 3) return -1;
    return 0;
}

void ADSBWorker::apply_phase_correction(uint16_t *mag) {
    int j;

    mag += 16;
    for (j = 0; j < (MODE_S_LONG_MSG_BITS - 1) * 2; j += 2) {
        if (mag[j] > mag[j + 1]) {
            mag[j + 2] = (mag[j + 2] * 5) / 4;
        } else {
            mag[j + 2] = (mag[j + 2] * 4) / 5;
        }

        if (j > 4 && mag[j - 4] == mag[j - 2] && mag[j - 2] == mag[j]) {
            mag[j + 2] = (mag[j + 2] * 3) / 2;
        }
    }
}

void ADSBWorker::detectMessage(uint16_t *mag, uint32_t maglen, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>& detectedMessages) {
    unsigned char bits[MODE_S_LONG_MSG_BITS];
    unsigned char msg[MODE_S_LONG_MSG_BYTES];
    uint16_t aux[MODE_S_LONG_MSG_BITS * 2];
    uint32_t j;
    int use_correction = 0;
    int aggressive = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < maglen - MODE_S_FULL_LEN * 2; j++) {
        int low, high, delta, i, errors;
        int good_message = 0;

        if (use_correction) goto good_preamble;

        if (!(mag[j] > mag[j + 1] &&
              mag[j + 1] < mag[j + 2] &&
              mag[j + 2] > mag[j + 3] &&
              mag[j + 3] < mag[j] &&
              mag[j + 4] < mag[j] &&
              mag[j + 5] < mag[j] &&
              mag[j + 6] < mag[j] &&
              mag[j + 7] > mag[j + 8] &&
              mag[j + 8] < mag[j + 9] &&
              mag[j + 9] > mag[j + 6])) {
            continue;
        }

        high = (mag[j] + mag[j+2] + mag[j+7] + mag[j+9]) / 6;

        if (mag[j+4] >= high || mag[j+5] >= high) {
            continue;
        }

        if (mag[j+11] >= high || mag[j+12] >= high || mag[j+13] >= high || mag[j+14] >= high) {
            continue;
        }

    good_preamble:
        if (use_correction) {
            if (j + MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US * 2 + sizeof(aux) / sizeof(uint16_t) <= maglen) {
                memcpy(aux, mag + j + MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US * 2, sizeof(aux));
                if (j && detect_out_of_phase(mag + j)) {
                    apply_phase_correction(mag + j);
                }
            }
        }

        errors = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < MODE_S_LONG_MSG_BITS * 2; i += 2) {
            if (j + i + MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US * 2 + 1 >= maglen) break;
            low = mag[j + i + MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US * 2];
            high = mag[j + i + MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US * 2 + 1];
            delta = low - high;
            if (delta < 0) delta = -delta;

            if (i > 0 && delta < 256) {
                bits[i / 2] = bits[i / 2 - 1];
            } else if (low == high) {
                bits[i / 2] = 2;
                if (i < MODE_S_SHORT_MSG_BITS * 2) errors++;
            } else if (low > high) {
                bits[i / 2] = 1;
            } else {
                bits[i / 2] = 0;
            }
        }

        if (use_correction && j + MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US * 2 + sizeof(aux) / sizeof(uint16_t) <= maglen) {
            memcpy(mag + j + MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US * 2, aux, sizeof(aux));
        }

        for (i = 0; i < MODE_S_LONG_MSG_BITS; i += 8) {
            msg[i / 8] =
                (bits[i] << 7) |
                (bits[i + 1] << 6) |
                (bits[i + 2] << 5) |
                (bits[i + 3] << 4) |
                (bits[i + 4] << 3) |
                (bits[i + 5] << 2) |
                (bits[i + 6] << 1) |
                (bits[i + 7]);
        }

        int msgtype = msg[0] >> 3;
        int msglen = mode_s_msg_len_by_type(msgtype) / 8;

        delta = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < msglen * 8 * 2; i += 2) {
            if (j + i + MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US * 2 + 1 >= maglen) break;
            delta += abs(mag[j + i + MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US * 2] - mag[j + i + MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US * 2 + 1]);
        }
        delta /= msglen * 4;

        if (delta < 10 * 255) {
            use_correction = 0;
            continue;
        }
        mode_s_msg mm;
        mode_s_decode(&mm, msg);

        if (errors == 0 || (aggressive && errors < 3)) {
            if (mm.crcok) {
                std::vector<unsigned char> decodedMsg(msg, msg + msglen);
                detectedMessages.push_back(decodedMsg);
                j += (MODE_S_PREAMBLE_US + (msglen * 8)) * 2;
                good_message = 1;
            }
        }

        if (!good_message && !use_correction) {
            j--;
            use_correction = 1;
        } else {
            use_correction = 0;
        }
    }
}

void ADSBWorker::mode_s_decode(mode_s_msg *mm, unsigned char *msg) {
    mm->msgtype = msg[0] >> 3;
    mm->msgbits = mode_s_msg_len_by_type(mm->msgtype);
    int msgBytes = mm->msgbits / 8;

    memcpy(mm->msg, msg, msgBytes);

    mm->crc = ((uint32_t)mm->msg[msgBytes - 3] << 16) |
              ((uint32_t)mm->msg[msgBytes - 2] << 8) |
              (uint32_t)mm->msg[msgBytes - 1];

    uint32_t crc2 = computeCRC(mm->msg, mm->msgbits);

    mm->errorbit = -1;
    mm->crcok = (mm->crc == crc2);

    int fix_errors = 0;
    int aggressive = 1;

    if (!mm->crcok && fix_errors && (mm->msgtype == 11 || mm->msgtype == 17)) {
        if ((mm->errorbit = fix_single_bit_errors(mm->msg, mm->msgbits)) != -1) {
            mm->crcok = true;
        } else if (aggressive && mm->msgtype == 17 &&
                   (mm->errorbit = fix_two_bits_errors(mm->msg, mm->msgbits)) != -1) {
            mm->crcok = true;
        }
    }

    if (!mm->crcok) {
        return;
    }

    mm->ca = mm->msg[0] & 7;
    mm->aa1 = mm->msg[1];
    mm->aa2 = mm->msg[2];
    mm->aa3 = mm->msg[3];
    mm->metype = mm->msg[4] >> 3;
    mm->mesub = mm->msg[4] & 0x07;
    mm->fs = mm->msg[0] & 7;
    mm->dr = (mm->msg[1] >> 3) & 31;
    mm->um = ((mm->msg[1] & 7) << 3) | (mm->msg[2] >> 5);

    int a, b, c, d;
    a = ((mm->msg[3] & 0x80) >> 5) | ((mm->msg[2] & 0x02) >> 0) | ((mm->msg[2] & 0x08) >> 3);
    b = ((mm->msg[3] & 0x02) << 1) | ((mm->msg[3] & 0x08) >> 2) | ((mm->msg[3] & 0x20) >> 5);
    c = ((mm->msg[2] & 0x01) << 2) | ((mm->msg[2] & 0x04) >> 1) | ((mm->msg[2] & 0x10) >> 4);
    d = ((mm->msg[3] & 0x01) << 2) | ((mm->msg[3] & 0x04) >> 1) | ((mm->msg[3] & 0x10) >> 4);
    mm->identity = a * 1000 + b * 100 + c * 10 + d;

    if (mm->msgtype == 11 || mm->msgtype == 17) {
        if (mm->crcok && mm->errorbit == -1) {
            uint32_t addr = (mm->aa1 << 16) | (mm->aa2 << 8) | mm->aa3;
            add_recently_seen_icao_addr(addr);
        }
    } else {
        if (!brute_force_ap(mm->msg, mm)) {
            mm->crcok = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    if (mm->msgtype == 0 || mm->msgtype == 4 || mm->msgtype == 16 || mm->msgtype == 20) {
        mm->altitude = decode_ac13_field(mm->msg, &mm->unit);
    }

    if (mm->msgtype == 17) {
        if (mm->metype >= 1 && mm->metype <= 4) {
            mm->aircraft_type = mm->metype - 1;
            if (sizeof(mm->flight) >= 9) {
                mm->flight[0] = ais_charset[mm->msg[5] >> 2];
                mm->flight[1] = ais_charset[((mm->msg[5] & 3) << 4) | (mm->msg[6] >> 4)];
                mm->flight[2] = ais_charset[((mm->msg[6] & 15) << 2) | (mm->msg[7] >> 6)];
                mm->flight[3] = ais_charset[mm->msg[7] & 63];
                mm->flight[4] = ais_charset[mm->msg[8] >> 2];
                mm->flight[5] = ais_charset[((mm->msg[8] & 3) << 4) | (mm->msg[9] >> 4)];
                mm->flight[6] = ais_charset[((mm->msg[9] & 15) << 2) | (mm->msg[10] >> 6)];
                mm->flight[7] = ais_charset[mm->msg[10] & 63];
                mm->flight[8] = '\0';
            } else {
                memset(mm->flight, 0, sizeof(mm->flight));
            }
        } else if (mm->metype >= 9 && mm->metype <= 18) {
            mm->fflag = mm->msg[6] & (1 << 2);
            mm->tflag = mm->msg[6] & (1 << 3);
            mm->altitude = decode_ac12_field(mm->msg, &mm->unit);
            mm->raw_latitude = ((mm->msg[6] & 3) << 15) | (mm->msg[7] << 7) | (mm->msg[8] >> 1);
            mm->raw_longitude = ((mm->msg[8] & 1) << 16) | (mm->msg[9] << 8) | mm->msg[10];
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "Decoding message:";
    qDebug() << "  Raw message bytes:";
    QString rawMessage;
    for (int i = 0; i < msgBytes; i++) {
        rawMessage += QString("%1 ").arg(mm->msg[i], 2, 16, QChar('0')).toUpper();
    }
    qDebug() << rawMessage;
    qDebug() << "  Computed CRC:" << QString("%1").arg(crc2, 6, 16, QChar('0')).toUpper();
    qDebug() << "  Extracted CRC:" << QString("%1").arg(mm->crc, 6, 16, QChar('0')).toUpper();
    qDebug() << "  CRC Match:" << mm->crcok;
    qDebug() << "  ICAO Address:" << QString("%1").arg((mm->aa1 << 16) | (mm->aa2 << 8) | mm->aa3, 6, 16, QChar('0')).toUpper();

    mm->phase_corrected = 0;
}

void ADSBWorker::add_recently_seen_icao_addr(uint32_t addr) {
    uint32_t h = icao_cache_hash_addr(addr);
    icaoCache[h].addr = addr;
    icaoCache[h].timestamp = time(NULL);
}

bool ADSBWorker::icao_addr_was_recently_seen(uint32_t addr) {
    uint32_t h = icao_cache_hash_addr(addr);
    IcaoCacheEntry entry = icaoCache[h];
    return entry.addr == addr && (time(NULL) - entry.timestamp) <= MODE_S_ICAO_CACHE_TTL;
}

uint32_t ADSBWorker::icao_cache_hash_addr(uint32_t addr) {
    addr = ((addr >> 16) ^ addr) * 0x45d9f3b;
    addr = ((addr >> 16) ^ addr) * 0x45d9f3b;
    addr = ((addr >> 16) ^ addr);
    return addr & (MODE_S_ICAO_CACHE_LEN - 1);
}

uint32_t ADSBWorker::computeCRC(const uint8_t* msg, int bits) {
    static std::map<std::pair<const uint8_t*, int>, uint32_t> crcCache;
    auto key = std::make_pair(msg, bits);

    if (crcCache.find(key) != crcCache.end()) {
        return crcCache[key];
    }

    uint32_t crc = 0;
    int offset = (bits == 112) ? 0 : (112 - 56);

    for (int j = 0; j < bits; j++) {
        int byte = j / 8;
        int bit = j % 8;
        int bitmask = 1 << (7 - bit);

        if (msg[byte] & bitmask) {
            crc ^= mode_s_checksum_table[j + offset];
        }
    }

    crc &= 0xFFFFFF;
    crcCache[key] = crc;
    return crc;
}

int ADSBWorker::fix_single_bit_errors(unsigned char *msg, int bits) {
    int j;
    unsigned char aux[MODE_S_LONG_MSG_BYTES];

    for (j = 0; j < bits; j++) {
        int byte = j / 8;
        int bitmask = 1 << (7 - (j % 8));
        uint32_t crc1, crc2;

        memcpy(aux, msg, bits / 8);
        aux[byte] ^= bitmask;

        crc1 = ((uint32_t)aux[(bits / 8) - 3] << 16) |
               ((uint32_t)aux[(bits / 8) - 2] << 8) |
               (uint32_t)aux[(bits / 8) - 1];
        crc2 = computeCRC(aux, bits);

        if (crc1 == crc2) {
            memcpy(msg, aux, bits / 8);
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int ADSBWorker::fix_two_bits_errors(unsigned char *msg, int bits) {
    int j, i;
    unsigned char aux[MODE_S_LONG_MSG_BYTES];

    for (j = 0; j < bits; j++) {
        int byte1 = j / 8;
        int bitmask1 = 1 << (7 - (j % 8));

        for (i = j + 1; i < bits; i++) {
            int byte2 = i / 8;
            int bitmask2 = 1 << (7 - (i % 8));
            uint32_t crc1, crc2;

            memcpy(aux, msg, bits / 8);

            aux[byte1] ^= bitmask1;
            aux[byte2] ^= bitmask2;

            crc1 = ((uint32_t)aux[(bits / 8) - 3] << 16) |
                   ((uint32_t)aux[(bits / 8) - 2] << 8) |
                   (uint32_t)aux[(bits / 8) - 1];
            crc2 = computeCRC(aux, bits);

            if (crc1 == crc2) {
                memcpy(msg, aux, bits / 8);
                return j | (i << 8);
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int ADSBWorker::mode_s_msg_len_by_type(int type) {
    if (type == 16 || type == 17 ||
        type == 19 || type == 20 ||
        type == 21)
        return MODE_S_LONG_MSG_BITS;
    else
        return MODE_S_SHORT_MSG_BITS;
}

int ADSBWorker::decode_ac13_field(unsigned char *msg, int *unit) {
    int m_bit = msg[3] & (1 << 6);
    int q_bit = msg[3] & (1 << 4);

    if (!m_bit) {
        *unit = MODE_S_UNIT_FEET;
        if (q_bit) {
            int n = ((msg[2] & 31) << 6) |
                    ((msg[3] & 0x80) >> 2) |
                    ((msg[3] & 0x20) >> 1) |
                    (msg[3] & 15);
            return n * 25 - 1000;
        }
    } else {
        *unit = MODE_S_UNIT_METERS;
    }
    return 0;
}

int ADSBWorker::decode_ac12_field(unsigned char *msg, int *unit) {
    int q_bit = msg[5] & 1;

    if (q_bit) {
        *unit = MODE_S_UNIT_FEET;
        int n = ((msg[5] >> 1) << 4) | ((msg[6] & 0xF0) >> 4);
        return n * 25 - 1000;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int ADSBWorker::brute_force_ap(unsigned char *msg, mode_s_msg *mm) {
    unsigned char aux[MODE_S_LONG_MSG_BYTES];
    int msgtype = mm->msgtype;
    int msgbits = mm->msgbits;

    if (msgtype == 0 || msgtype == 4 || msgtype == 5 || msgtype == 16 ||
        msgtype == 20 || msgtype == 21 || msgtype == 24) {
        uint32_t addr;
        uint32_t crc;
        int lastbyte = (msgbits / 8) - 1;

        memcpy(aux, msg, msgbits / 8);

        crc = computeCRC(aux, msgbits);
        aux[lastbyte] ^= crc & 0xff;
        aux[lastbyte - 1] ^= (crc >> 8) & 0xff;
        aux[lastbyte - 2] ^= (crc >> 16) & 0xff;

        addr = (aux[lastbyte - 2] << 16) | (aux[lastbyte - 1] << 8) | aux[lastbyte];

        if (icao_addr_was_recently_seen(addr)) {
            mm->aa1 = aux[lastbyte - 2];
            mm->aa2 = aux[lastbyte - 1];
            mm->aa3 = aux[lastbyte];
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void ADSBWorker::printMessageMM(const mode_s_msg *mm) {
    QString messageStr;
    QTextStream stream(&messageStr);
    stream << "Decoded message:\n";
    stream << "  Downlink Format: " << mm->msgtype << "\n";
    stream << "  ICAO Address: " << QString("%1").arg((mm->aa1 << 16) | (mm->aa2 << 8) | mm->aa3, 6, 16, QChar('0')).toUpper() << "\n";

    if (mm->msgtype == 17) {
        stream << "  Message Type: " << mm->metype << "\n";
        stream << "  Subtype: " << mm->mesub << "\n";
        if (mm->metype >= 1 && mm->metype <= 4) {
            stream << "  Flight: " << QString(mm->flight) << "\n";
        }
        if (mm->metype >= 9 && mm->metype <= 18) {
            stream << "  Altitude: " << mm->altitude << "\n";
            stream << "  Latitude (raw): " << mm->raw_latitude << "\n";
            stream << "  Longitude (raw): " << mm->raw_longitude << "\n";
        }
    } else if (mm->msgtype == 11) {
        stream << "  Capability: " << mm->ca << "\n";
        stream << "  Identity: " << mm->identity << "\n";
    }

    qDebug() << messageStr;
    emit messageDecoded(messageStr);
}

Can someone check if somewhere I made a mistake? I'm new at this stuff, so only learning
Thanks beforehand!
